# I create a new Wordpress site on a folder, but it redirects to the old one

Tags: wordpress

i have a wordpress wich is laquintaresort.net
I have an old one so i updated, but i create the new one on laquintaresort.net/new
So, when it was done, i simply change some settings and the new one was working.

Everything is working fine, BUT, when i go to the root domain (laquintaresort.net) it goes to mu old website, BUT, if i click on a page, like “Actividades” it goes to my new site.
The front page is the one wich is not working.

To put live the new version i just change the WordPress URL to /new/ and the URL site is just the same (the root one, laquintaresort.net).
I also change index.php to /new/ in order to redirect files load.

I did not erase the old site, first, i can do it, but its not the idea, the idea is to keep the new one replacing the old one.

Any idea of what i missing to do in order to redirect user to the new site?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

At index.php on my root folder i add

require( dirname( **FILE** ) . '**/new/**wp-blog-header.php' );

And solved

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good method that you have used to solve your problem, though it may work.
you could try something like a redirect by changing values in .htaccess (provided you have cloned the site in the subdirectory)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ new [L]
```

If you want an external redirect (which cause the visiting browser to show the redirected URL), set the R flag there as well:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /new [L,R=301]
```